# How to delete a directory from terminal?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to delete a directory after a series of events take place. That being said, I need to be able to place this in a file to execute once said events take place.

Comment: By the way, no I haven't tried much because I' unsure what it will do.

Comment: BTW - such a noob I was

Answer (score 0):

You mean something simple like

```
rm -r -- "$dir"
```

Comment: What if you are currently within a subdirectory? Where would you end up (pwd)?

Comment: @les your cwd won't change, but future calls to lookup the cwd will return "no such file or directory".

Comment: @les first change your directory; for example `cd ..` and then `rm -r "$dir"`

Comment: @les It wouldn't make sense to delete the directory which contains this script, would it?

Comment: @HaukeLaging it might :)

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand what you ask, you need a script you can call after your events ?

Assuming you use bash, create a file (touch myFile.sh), make it executable (chmod +x myFile.sh), then edit :

```
#!/bin/bash
# The location of the directorie to delete
dir="/My/dir/location"

# Testing if directory exist ([[ -d]]) and deleting the directory
# Using -r for delete a directory, -f to avoid human confirmation
[[ -d ${dir} ]] && rm -Rf ${dir}
```

Be carefull, no trash with this options -Rf, directory AND files inside will be deleted for ever. 
If you're not sure of what you're doing, replace the last line, for your tests, by :

```
[[ -d ${dir} ]] && mv ${dir} /tmp
```

Is it what you needed ?

Guess it help !

Enjoy !

Comment: Is there any confirmation on this? I've been past this, but will test it soon.